# Python send escpos command to thermal printer character size issue

Tags: python, thermal-printer, escpos

I need to send escpos to a thermal receipt printer. I am running into issues with specifying character size, which is described [https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=34]. In Python I write this command as

```
#ESC @ for initiate the printer
string = b'\x1b\x40'
#GS ! command in the doc corresponding to 4 times character height and width
string = string + b'\x1d' + b'\x21' + b'\x30' + b'\x03' 
string = string + bytes('hello world')
```

In the first line I initiated the printer corresponding to ESC @
In the second line I wanted to specify the character size to be 4x height and width (see the links to the doc).
In the third line I print out the text.

The problem is that the text printed out has 4x width, but not 4 times height. I have also tried to write the character size as two commands

```
string = string + b'\x1d' + b'\x21' + b'\x30'
string = string + b'\x1d' + b'\x21' + b'\x03'
```

In this case, my text is printed out with 4 times height but not 4 times width. I am pretty sure that I have misread the doc, but I don't know how else I should write the command in order to achieve both 4 times height and width.

Also [examples](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=269) exist for the GS ! syntax in escpos, and there it seems to be written as GS ! 0x11 to achieve both 2 times width and height. This doesn't seems to make sense from the table. I am aware that python-escpos exists, however it doesn't work on windows 10 for my usb printer.

Comment: There are at least two syntax errors in the code you listed, which is quite odd since you seem to say that the program actually runs...? That makes me think that you didn't actually post the code you used and which works. Also, what is the Python version?

Comment: I am using Python 3.81. The code is a minimal snippet to reproduce the problem. Can you point out the syntax error for me?

Comment: string = b'\x1b\x40 is not terminated.

Comment: string = string b'\x1d' + b'\x21' + b'\x30' seems to miss a + after the second "string".

Comment: The reason I write this is that as long as there are syntax errors, the code is hard to read, as you have to try to guess what was probably meant, and then it's harder to focus on what you are actually asking...

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out for me. It is typo from my side. In my script the syntax is all right with respect to the + and '.

Comment: I seem to have found the problem anyway; see suggested answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From reading the docs, it seems to me that you would have to use

```
b'\x1d' + b'\x21' + b'\x33'
```

to get 4 times magnification in height as well as width. The two '3' indicate the magnifications minus one. The first is width, the second is height.

So the problem seems to be that you split width and height into two bytes. They should be collected into one byte.

So, in total:

```
#ESC @ for initiate the printer
string = b'\x1b\x40'

#GS ! command in the doc corresponding to 4 times character height and width
string = string + b'\x1d' + b'\x21' + b'\x33' 
string = string + bytes('hello world')
```

Or, in another way:

```py
def initialize():
    # Code for initialization of the printer.
    return b'\x1b\x40'

def magnify(wm, hm):
    # Code for magnification of characters.
    # wm: Width magnification from 1 to 8. Normal width is 1, double is 2, etc.
    # hm: Height magnification from 1 to 8. Normal height is 1, double is 2, etc.
    return bytes([0x1d, 16*(wm-1) + (hm-1)])

def text(t, encoding="ascii"):
    # Code for sending text.
    return bytes(t, encoding)

string = initialize() + magnify(4, 4) + text('hello world')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out. I misread the doc. When the hex for 4x width is 30, I thought it is value 30. Is it correctly understood of me that the first value should be 3 and if the last value is 0, then height will be normal size (1x)?

Comment: \x30 will be 4 x width, 1 x height. \x41 will be 5 times width, 2 times height, etc.

Comment: This can make it quite difficult to code. For example say that we want 1 in width and 2 in height. It is not possible in Python to code it as say a = '\x' + str(2) + str(3) followed by a = bytes(a)

Comment: @jxw Like this: m = 16*(widthmagnification-1) + (heightmagnification-1). And then a=bytes([m]). It's bit manipulation. Double width, triple height would be widthmagnification=2, heightmagnification=3, m would be 16*(1-1)+(3-1)=16+2=18, and a would be bytes([18]).

Comment: @jxw I expanded the answer to show what I meant with the calculation of magnification.